# Replace a particular value based on condition using groupby in pandas

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe as shown below

```
ID    Sector    Usage     Price
1     A         R         20
2     A         C         100
3     A         R         40
4     A         R         1
5     A         C         200
6     A         C         1
7     A         C         1
8     A         R         1
1     B         R         40
2     B         C         200
3     B         R         60
4     B         R         1
5     B         C         400
6     B         C         1
7     B         C         1
8     B         R         1
```

From the above I would like to replace the Price=1  with average Price of Sector and Usage combination other than 1.

Expected Output:

```
    ID    Sector    Usage     Price
    1     A         R         20
    2     A         C         100
    3     A         R         40
    4     A         R         30
    5     A         C         200
    6     A         C         150
    7     A         C         150
    8     A         R         30
    1     B         R         40
    2     B         C         200
    3     B         R         60
    4     B         R         50
    5     B         C         400
    6     B         C         300
    7     B         C         300
    8     B         R         50
```

For example in row 4 Sector = A, Usage=R Price=1 has to be replaced by average of Sector = A and Usage=R, ie (20+40)/2 = 30

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea is first replace `1` to missing values by [`Series.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) and then use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for means per groups used for replaced:

```
m = df['Price'] == 1
s = df.assign(Price=df['Price'].mask(m)).groupby(['Sector','Usage'])['Price'].transform('mean')
df['Price'] = np.where(m, s, df['Price']).astype(int)
```

Or:

```
s = df['Price'].mask(df['Price'] == 1)
mean = df.assign(Price=s).groupby(['Sector','Usage'])['Price'].transform('mean')
df['Price'] = s.fillna(mean).astype(int)
```

---

```
print (df)
    ID Sector Usage  Price
0    1      A     R     20
1    2      A     C    100
2    3      A     R     40
3    4      A     R     30
4    5      A     C    200
5    6      A     C    150
6    7      A     C    150
7    8      A     R     30
8    1      B     R     40
9    2      B     C    200
10   3      B     R     60
11   4      B     R     50
12   5      B     C    400
13   6      B     C    300
14   7      B     C    300
15   8      B     R     50
```

Comment: @ jezrael for my data it is showing very big negative numbers

Comment: @ALI - All data are numeric? If check `print (s)` and `print (mean)` there is problematic output?

Comment: prints(s)
0         -208673575494294944.0000
1          -97601820495637856.0000
2          -97601820495637856.0000
3          -97601820495637856.0000
4          -97601820495637856.0000

Comment: print(s) is some giving some values like the above one. But I dont have any Price with negative in actual.

Comment: @ALI - If testing for first 100 rows of data, where is at least one 1 values still problem?

Comment: @ALI - What is pandas version?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207762/discussion-between-ali-and-jezrael).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60305889/time-difference-in-days-based-on-specific-condition-in-pandas, kindly check above question, no one answered.

Comment: @ALI - sure, give me some time.